# phpmyadmin reloads/loops login screen (IIS 7)

Tags: iis, redirect, authentication, phpmyadmin

After submitting my UN and PW into PMA login screen, it just reloads the login screen. I have cleared browser cache (Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari) and have cookies enabled. PMA is on a Windows 2008 server running IIS 7.

I have read numerous posts on here and around the web, but have not found a solution.

Anyone have other ideas specific to Windows OS and IIS7?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any hints in your webserver or PHP error logs? Does MySQL show any attempt to connect?

Comment: Cleared cache, cookies are enabled. Made sure timestamp on server was correct. Tried FF, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera -- nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

So not too long ago I changed the upload_tmp_dir in my php.ini (config) file and guess I hadn't logged into PMA since then because I never noticed a problem. Anyway, went into my PHP error log files and noticed this error: "PHP Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct...". So I went into my php.ini file again, changed the line "session.save_path=C:\olddirectory" to "session.save_path=C:\newdirectory" (C:\newdirectory is the same as the upload_tmp_dir location, that I changed). Now it works!

And the "session.save_path" line you change is the one under [WebPIChanges], where error_log and upload_tmp_dir are also directed – user3092019 just now  edit